# gcloud console can't view gke resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm testing permissions on GCP on new project, I've created a user and gave basic `storage.objects.get` and `storage.objects.list` permissions and all work, but when I moved to GKE it stopped no matter how many permissions (`container.clusters.*` or `container.pods.*` or the role `Kubernetes Engine Cluster Viewer` he can't view the resources with the error message

```sh
Can't access project settings for project <my_project> on service container.googleapis.com [view=CONSUMER_VIEW].
```

any thoughts what might be the issue ?

I also enabled the API services

```sh
gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable compute.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable serviceusage.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable servicemanagement.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable sql-component.googleapis.com
```

anyone see anything basic I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1):

See the pre-defined [GKE roles](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam#predefined); while you might be lacking another role/permission (on the project itself, instead of GKE). It is impossible to tell without even knowing which command you've ran.

I'd suggest to [enable troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/troubleshooting-access#gcloud):

```
gcloud services enable policytroubleshooter.googleapis.com --project=project-id
gcloud config set project project-id
gcloud policy-troubleshoot iam resource --principal-email=email --permission=permission
gcloud policy-troubleshoot iam //cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects/my-project --permission=resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy --principal-email=foo@example.com
```

This should provide an accurate insight what is going wrong and why

(some of the dummy arguments obviously require substitution).

Comment: the only commands I have run are the ones above with gcloud services enable, other than that I'm properly set to `gcloud config set project <my_project>` - the error message was on the console - but ok I'll test with troubleshooter

Comment: Even if the error message is being in the web-console ...some command must have triggered that error message. And it's a whole lot easier to tell, when knowing the command and the error message.

Comment: After testing with troubleshooter enabled, edit your question with your latest findings so we can dig further.