# ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=Failed

Tags: kubernetes, snakemake

Hi I am getting following error

`ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=Failed precondition when calling the ServiceConsumerManager: tenantmanager::185014: Consumer 370525719069 should enable service:container.googleapis.com before generating a service account`.

can someone help me ?

Comment: Did my solution help ? Otherwise what kind of environment you are working on and what kind of command you are running ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should enable API service - container.googleapis.com, execute command:

```
$ gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com
```

Please take a look at this intorduction especially: [environment setup and cluster creation on GKE](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-deploy-website-on-gke#2).

See more: [gcp-enabling-disabling-services](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable), [troubleshooting-enabling-gcp-services](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/troubleshooting-access#gcloud), [enabling-gcp-services-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751262/gcloud-console-cant-view-gke-resources).

**Another option:**

It hard to answer due to lack of important additional information (e.g. environment )but  such error may indicate that you are working on some kind of multi-tenancy environment. Make sure that you have proper rights to create new clusters:

> Assign roles using IAM
> You can control access to Google Cloud
> resources through IAM policies. Start by identifying the groups needed for your organization and their scope of operations, then assign the appropriate IAM role to the group. Use Google Groups to efficiently
> assign and manage IAM for users.

See: [enterprise-multitenancy-roles](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/best-practices/enterprise-multitenancy%23assign-iam-roles&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1603872827370000&usg=AFQjCNEfcBMv755zdpSipKsHPuH8hg_rwA).

Also take a look on best practices how to set up [multi-tenant-cluster-gke-enterprise](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/best-practices/enterprise-multitenancy).

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred when trying to create a Google Kubernetes Cluster on a Shared VPC.
The Shared VPC host project was missing the `container.googleapis.com` API activation.

Activate the `container.googleapis.com` API on the Shared VPC host project to solve this issue.

Comment: via GUI: `https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/container.googleapis.com?returnUrl=%2Fkubernetes%2Flist%3Freferrer%3Dsearch%26project%3Dprj-bartuszak-dev&project=prj-bartuszak-dev` (replace prj-bartuszak-dev with ur project name)